# Como consultar dados salvos em JSON no DbContext do .Net Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, asp.net-core

Olá, estou com uma dúvida em relação a como realizar consultar uma lista ou até mesmo um unico registro que foi salvo no banco de dados no formato JSON.

Por Exemplo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses são os dados salvos em formato JSON no banco, mas agora quero realizar uma consulta por um UserLogged Id especifico ou um produto

como consigo realizar essa consulta ??

Comment: Se o objetivo for trabalhar com json, recomendava usar uma base de dados mais apropriada, mas vc pode encontrar a resposta para a sua pergunta e mais informações na documentação da Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @tvdias Obrigado pela ajuda.